# Translate 'Loves' at the end of a letter

Tags: перевод

I am translating a mail from English to Russian and the mail has a word 'Loves' as a part of the signature:

```
...letter text

Loves

Ben
```

(Ben is the sender's name). What my friend mean with this word? Does he say he loves the addressees or does he wish them love?

A bit of clarification: The letter is absolutely informal, it is from the mailing list in a game and is addressed to a group of players. And the the contents of the letter are completely unrelated to love in any form :-)

How would you translate that: "С люовью", "Люблю" or "Любви" or something else?

I was trying to find the answer with Google and Yandex but it seems to be a bit of specific and narrow so I just drowned in tips on how to sign letters.

P.S. Please sorry my poor English

Comment: Is it 'loves' not 'love'? Looks like a typo.

Comment: Does not look like a proper English to me. "Loves" may be used in a sense similar to "Hugs" and "Kisses".

Comment: @VaNdal He does write "Loves", not "love" every time. That plural form is is what embarrasses me.

Comment: @Alexander I don't know if English is his native. Players from all over the world here -- Asia, Europe, America

Comment: If he's not a native speaker then we have some many options... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"С любовью" sounds like the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Будь то "love" или "loves", скорее всего, имеется в виду что-то вроде "целую" или "обнимаю, целую". 
Тепла примерно столько же, сколько в письмах между родственниками.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on the nature of the letter. There is every chance it is rather informal, so the best translation, in my opinion, would be *"люблю тебя*" (*вас,* if addressed to more than one person)